# Very Hard System of Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, substitution

Solve the system of equations:

\begin{cases}
\sqrt{xy}(x + 3y)(3x + y) = 14 \\
(x + y)(x^2 + y^2 + 14xy) = 36.
\end{cases}

Suppose $x + y = m$ and $xy = n$. So I get

\begin{cases}
(3m^2+4n) \sqrt n = 14 \\
m^3+12mn=36
\end{cases}

So can express $m$ in terms of $n$ but I want only real solution.
Is there a faster way?

Comment: It will help you greatly to note that these equations are transposable, that is, $(x,y)=(X,Y)$ is a solution, so too is $(x,y)=(Y,X)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x+y=2k\sqrt{xy}.$
Thus, by AM-GM $k\geq1$ and from the first and the second equations we obtain:
$$18\sqrt{xy}(3x^2+3y^2+10xy)=7(x+y)(x^2+y^2+14xy)$$ or
$$18(12k^2+4)=7\cdot2k(4k^2+12)$$ or
$$7k^3-27k^2+21k-9=0$$ or
$$7k^3-21k^2-6k^2+18k+3k-9=0$$ or
$$(k-3)(7k^2-6k+3)=0,$$ which gives $k=3$ and $$x+y=6\sqrt{xy}.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Yes thank you for good solution :)

Comment: @Heart You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Solving the second equation for $n$ we get $$n=-1/12\,{\frac {{m}^{3}-36}{m}}$$ for $$m\neq 0$$ plugging this in your first equation we get
$$1/6\, \left( 3\,{m}^{2}-1/3\,{\frac {{m}^{3}-36}{m}} \right) \sqrt {-3
\,{\frac {{m}^{3}-36}{m}}}=14
$$
so now we square and factorize this equation we obtain:
$$-16\, \left( m-3 \right)  \left( {m}^{2}+3 \right)  \left( {m}^{2}+3\,
m+3 \right)  \left( {m}^{2}-3\,m+3 \right)  \left( {m}^{2}+3\,m+9
 \right) 
=0$$
I hope you will find all solutions.